# Terminology question: "Module derivations" of the form $\mu \colon M \rightarrow M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, homological-algebra, graded-modules, differential-graded-algebras

Let $R$ be a graded ring endowed with a graded derivation $d \colon R \rightarrow R$ of degree $k$. Let $M$ be a graded $R$-module. Is there a standard name for degree $k$ maps $\mu \colon M \rightarrow M$ which satisfy a graded Leibniz rule with respect to $d$? That is, maps which satisfy
$$ \mu \left( r \cdot m \right) = dr \cdot m + (-1)^{k \cdot \left| r \right|} r \cdot \mu \left( m \right). $$
When $k=1, d^2 = 0$ and $\mu^2 = 0$ then this compatibility is precisely what is required to endow $M$ with a structure of a DG-module over $(R,d)$ but I'm interested in the more general case but even then, I only found references that treat the pair $\left( M, \mu \right)$ and not the map $\mu$ seperately.

It seems tempting to call such maps "module derivations on $M$ over $d$" or something like that but googling module derivations gives me mostly things of the form $R \rightarrow M$ where $R$ is a ring and $M$ is a bimodule and not of the form $M \rightarrow M$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You are again and again misusing the comment section for posting answers. Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information. See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments for more information why posting answers in comments is bad practice.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Great, thanks! I think I'll adopt your terminology.